Switching accounts in Pyrogram
I have a user bot, that may sometimes encounter pyrogram.errors.UserBannedInChannel. I need to change Client with new api_id and api_hash.
I tried to do something like this:
app: Client = Client(name=SESSION_NAME, api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

try:
    ...
except pyrogram.errors.UserBannedInChannel:
    app.name = 'new_session'
    app.api_hash = 'api_hash_2'
    app.api_id = 'api_id_2'
    app.reload()

But it doesn't seem to work for me.
compose() is not an option for me.
What can I do?

Why not just create a new client?

Could you provide an example, please? I just have a main function:
async def main() -> None:     await app.start()     await idle()     await app.stop() 
This function is called first

maybe run again app: Client = Client(...)  with new values.
